# Re-size Canvas without reducing its width and height (Coordinates)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, canvas

I have drawn a picture in canvas and paint some points according to user mouse clicks. I Used mathematical calculation in order to show some panel names in picture once user hover over as tool tips. I use canvas coordinates and scales percentages. 
My problem is when i re-size window to smaller window (I used Mozilla responsive mode Mobile device) the it gives wrong coordinates.

Actual size of canvas is - 460 ,550
In mobile window mode it is around 250,350

I have used following style

```
#splatExteriorImage {
    background-image: url(../images/SPLAT1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 0;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
```

How can i re-size canvas without reducing its coordinates.
Thanks In Advance,

Comment: Do you define width and height attributes in <canvas> tag in html?

Comment: Are you talking about the HTML5 `canvas` tag? Please post your HTML.

Comment: Yes My Canvas HTML5 -                                                                    <canvas id="splatExteriorImage" width="460" height="550"></canvas>

Comment: I can re-size the canvas correctly by applying a responsive css. The problem is when re-size the canvas the coordinates goes wrong. Earlier the maximum coordinate was (460,550). After re-sizing it has become around 250,350.

Answer (score 0):

The dimensions of a canvas rendering surface are independent of the dimensions of the canvas tag.

For example:

`<canvas width=400 height=300 style="width: 800px; height: 600px;"></canvas>`

You can change the width and height of the drawing surface independently of the height in CSS.

To specifically change the height of the rendering surface, use

`setAttribute("height", "500");`

Comment: I can re-size the canvas correctly by applying a responsive css. The problem is when re-size the canvas the coordinates goes wrong. Earlier the maximum coordinate was (460,550). After re-sizing it has become around 250,350.